# How to make a Transition between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, transition

Could somebody help me,take a look at this [website](http://www.colouredlines.com.au/),and tell me please,what function is used for the nice transition when you click on some of the menu bars,it goes smoothly to another page without loading whitescreen.

If you know,tell me, what it is or how can i do that,or even both :D please give me answer below.Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you can't see,the website is http://www.colouredlines.com.au/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give a look to the Sourcecode of the Page, you'll see that all the needen Pages are already loaded in the DOM. (One Page structure I guess, or maybe as Asychronoumus loading).

However all the Pages have their own DIV container, which are linked to the Navigation Bar.
On click on each Navigation Element, make a transition of the prefered DIV's.

You can either choose the fade effect (which is using on the Page you show us), or even some other cool effects with bouncing, or even if you know how to manupulate CSS with jQuery, then your own Animation / Transition too. Here's a link to the jQuery API [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)
.

I would do it like this:

```js
$(function(){
  // Setup your Variables first
  var nav = $('.navigation ul li');
  var all_pages = $('.pages .page');
  var active = 'active';
  var target, page;
  
  
  // On Click do the stuff to get some transition
  nav.on('click', function(){
    // Get the Target
    target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    page = $('.page[data-page='+target+']');
    
    // Hide all pages here (maybe it would be a better idea to target .page.active)
    all_pages.fadeOut('slow').removeClass(active);

    // FadeIn the target Page
    page.fadeIn('slow').addClass(active);
  
  });
  
  
  // fallback to first page when the target is not set on page load
  if(!target)      nav.first().trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.main { position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; font-family:'Verdana'; font-size:13px; }

.navigation { border:0px solid red; width:150px; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; }
.navigation ul { list-style:none; width:auto; margin:0px; padding:0px; }
.navigation ul li { display:block; height:30px; border:0px solid green; line-height:30px; white-space:nowrap; cursor:pointer; padding:0px 20px; }

.pages { position:absolute; left:150px; right:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; border:0px solid blue; }
.page { position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; display:none; min-height:500px; }

.page.active { }

.page:nth-child(1),
.navigation ul li:nth-child(1) { background:lightgreen; }
.page:nth-child(2),
.navigation ul li:nth-child(2) { background:maroon; }
.page:nth-child(3),
.navigation ul li:nth-child(3) { background:wheat; }
.page:nth-child(4),
.navigation ul li:nth-child(4) { background:cyan; }
.page:nth-child(5),
.navigation ul li:nth-child(5) { background:salmon; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='main'>
  <div class='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li data-target='1'>First Link</li>
    <li data-target='2'>Second Page</li>
    <li data-target='who'>Who I am</li>
    <li data-target='location'>Location</li>
    <li data-target='5'>Oter Stuff</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class='pages'>
    <div class='page' data-page='1'> Here is the first page ... </div>
    <div class='page' data-page='2'> here is the seocnd one</div>
    <div class='page' data-page='who'> Who I am?</div>
    <div class='page' data-page='location'> Location </div>    
    <div class='page' data-page='5'> Oter Stuff </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you get the Idea behind the Code to get the result you want :)
Btw, I made this quickly HTML Markup to get a Similar effect for the transitions.
You'll need to add some more Animation Stuff for the Navigation to get the "on mouse over slide the names up etc" stuff - propably easy done with :hover syntax of CSS.

Hope this helps, ps. this is my first Post, I may have some mistakes in there.
And yes, there should be a better HTML Buildup as my Snippet does for now.

regards
Gkiokan